# Parsing JSON with angularjs with chosen select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have two urls where I call two json objects.

authors.json

```
[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Dan Brown",
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "name":"Steve Gates",
    }
]
```

books.js

```
[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "author_id":"1",
    "bookname":"Advance Programming"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "author_id":"1",
    "bookname":"Advanced Programming"
    },
    {
    "id":"3",
    "author_id":"1",
    "bookname":"C++ involved beyond 1"
    },
    {
    "id":"4",
    "author_id":"1",
    "bookname":"C++ involved beyond 2"
    },
    {
    "id":"5",
    "author_id":"2",
    "bookname":"C++ involved beyond 3"
    },
    {
    "id":"6",
    "author_id":"2",
    "bookname":"Java involved beyond"
    }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display a list of all books for chosen author from selected dropdown.

So far my HTML looks something like this.

```
<div ng-controller="authorSelectController">
    <select class="form-control" id="authors" ng-model="selectedAuthor">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">- Select Author -</option> 
        <option ng-repeat="author in authors" value="{{author.id}}">{{author.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <div ng-model="showBooks">
        //Show a list of books here
    </div>
</div>
```

my JS controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('authorSelectController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('../assets/js/data/authors.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.authors = data;
    });
}]);
```

Currently the authors get populate from the json, however I am unsure how to proceed from here to achieve what I want to do.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```
 <div ng-repeat="book in books | filter:{'author_id':selectedAuthor}">
        {{book.id}} :: {{book.bookname}}
 </div>
```

In the above code `books` is the array of all the books and `selectedAuthor` the selected author ID.

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14411/

**EDIT:** If you also want to display the author name one way of doing it is storing the authorName globally in one variable and updating it whenever the dropdown value is changed using [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) .
Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14415/

Comment: but how and when do I call the second json?

Comment: @BaconJuice You can just store the whole json directly and it would be filtered accordingly using filter

Comment: @BaconJuice Check the updated answer ... I added a working fiddle

Comment: hi @maandoo, just a follow up question. What is I wanted to show the Author along with the book id and book name as well? 1 :: Advance Programming :: Dan Brown